# Configuring Glassfish to use Equinox

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, osgi, bundle, equinox

Can anyone explain or point me to a good resource on configuring Glassfish 3.1.1 to use the Equinox 3.7 OSGI runtime, and creating/running some simple OSGI bundle for it? Trying to work my way up to deploying an RAP application on glassfish as OSGI bundle but haven't really been able to get off the ground.

Comment: Just one quick question, why can't you deploy a RAP application on Felix?

Comment: I was under the impression that there were some compatibility issues. So far I've been trying to deploy one to a servlet container as shown here http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rap.help%2Fhelp%2Fhtml%2Fadvanced%2Fdeployment.html. However, while I can launch the application using the eclipse's browser, I am unable to launch the WAR file obtained when exporting it using glassfish. I've been unable to find anything on troubleshooting it. If you could show me any way to deploy a rap application as a war file or through glassfish's osgi runtime I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty simple:

1. Just copy equinox jar (org.eclipse.osgi_$version.jar) to glassfish/osgi/equinox/.
2. Set an environment variable: GlassFish_Platform=Equinox
3. Start GlassFish.
4. Now deploy your OSGi bundles by just copying them to glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/bundles/

For more information, see GlassFish/OSGi guide at 
http://glassfish.java.net/public/GF-OSGi-Features.pdf